# What does Rails mean when it reports spending time rendering a view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Here's an excerpt from my Rails log:

```
Rendered songs/_song_list (683.4ms)
Completed in 841ms (View: 633, DB: 159) | 200 OK
```

What does Rails mean when it reports spending 633ms rendering the view?

In this particular case I'm iterating through a collection of items and printing an `<li>` for each (as the name of the partial suggests) -- is Rails spending that 633ms concatenating strings? I feel like that (or any other CPU-bound operation) should be roughly infinitely fast.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you aren't fetching from the database on every item. Preload everything you will need with the `include` option on find, or else, while the View is running, you will be running tons of queries and initializing new ActiveRecord objects, which is a huge time-waster.

Comment: Do database queries run within the view count towards the "View" number or the "DB" number in `Completed in 841ms (View: 633, DB: 159)`

Comment: My thought would be that they should, but I wouldn't depend on it - also, DB doesn't include object instantiation.

Answer (score 0):

`View` in this case means *everything*: The bootstrap, includes, initializations, everything. It still seems like a lot, though. What does time look like in a view that does nothing?